# Unable to setup user registry with "non-LDAP external registry"

Tags: windows, rtc

I am not able to setup user registry in RTC's JTS setup.
I selected "`non-LDAP external registry`" option and tried by giving users as "`JAdmin`", "`Administrator`", etc.
On click of next it is giving me error message

```
TypeError: 'this.currentForm.statusMsgHandler' is null or not an object
```

and Warning:

```
You need to be authenticated as a user from LDAP to 
import your user and assign licenses. 
Ensure the application container settings are configured correctly 
for LDAP, restart the server, and log in with a user from the LDAP 
directory to continue.
```

I think even if I am selecting "`non-LDAP external registry`" it is considering "`LDAP`" option and trying to connect to LDAP (According to log)

```
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: 
DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation 
a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1 ];     
Remaining name: 'ou=people,dc=jazz,dc=net'
```

Please help out to get over it!

Answer (score 0):

I configured RTC using OpenDJ LDAP.

Comment: Can you leave some details/screenshots, for others to benefit from your solution?